# Crash report mail by crash rate

Tags: crashlytics

I need to setup crash rate , for exzample

If the crash rate had not more than 98% so that it will be send mail to me.

How can I do , thanks.

none

none

none

Answer (score 0):

This is not built out in fabric, but once you migrate your app over to firebase, you can use a combination of big query and cloud functions with Google Analytics to achieve this.

Comment: Hi Chintan

Is there API function from the Fabric ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.. Fabric does not provide any APIs.